# Inequality of c_str() and char* in C++

Tags: c++, twitter, oauth, libcurl

I believe that I just tracked down the bug that's been haunting me for the past couple days, but the implications of it are giving me a major headache.

I'm on a macOS mojave machine, using the local libcurl tool (in /usr/lib), but I don't think cURL itself is the problem.

I've been trying to submit an OAuth2 request to Twitter, using the following code, all headers correctly supplied (not pictured).

```
// supplying https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials for ease of use
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
std::string grantType = "grant_type=client_credentials";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, grantType.c_str());
```

However, this fails with the status code

```
{"errors":[{"code":170,"message":"Missing required parameter: grant_type","label":"forbidden_missing_parameter"}]}
```

Confused, I gave this a shot:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
```

Which works perfectly:

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIMu6QAAAAAArr86Rv2W70fTicd4yAir7..."}
```

So either I don't understand a pivotal aspect of C++ or I've broken the universe — why does calling c_str() not result in the same output?

I've also been running the following in a separate project to try and make sense of what's going on.

```
std::string string1 = "test";
char* string2 = "test";
assert((strcmp(string1.c_str(), string2)) || (string1.c_str() == string2));
```

Why does defining a char* not produce the same value as defining a string and then calling c_str()?

Comment: The `std::string` destroys its string when it goes out of scope, but the `const char*` literal does not get destroyed. Could it be that `curl_easy_setopt` requires the passed string to live longer than the function containing the `std::string`?

Comment: I strongly recommend stepping through your code with a debugger so that you can inspect the value of `grantType` and `grantType.c_str()`

Comment: Thank you so much, ensuring that the string doesn't get destroyed out of scope worked perfectly!  Just tried (temporarily)
"curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
std::string* s = new std::string("grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, s->c_str());"

Comment: Not sure how to credit you with the answer, if you want to create one I'll accept it (or I can just make one which references your comment).

Comment: @Makiah "*ensuring that the string doesn't get destroyed out of scope worked perfectly!*" - you would have known that had you [read the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) beforehand. And FYI, your "solution" to `new` the string is a memory leak waiting to happen, if you don't `delete` the string after libcurl finishes using it

Comment: That's fair, but part of the reason I mentioned "temporarily" above was to point out that my "new string()" fix was not going to remain as-is or without a corresponding "delete", this was merely a quick way to diagnose whether this was in fact the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to actually be a string lifecycle issue, which alter igel pointed out: CURL_POSTFIELDS must access the string value at a later point in execution, but at which point the string would've already gone out of scope and been removed from memory.  Creating the variable as a parameter of the method must automatically create a char* literal that isn't destroyed by the compiler as quickly, leading to the behavior I outlined above.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is documented behavior in libcurl's documentation for [CURL_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html): "*The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes. This behaviour can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the [CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) option.*"

Comment: That's a keyword I wasn't even aware of, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Just considering your second project, the second part of the assert check in the code:

```
std::string string1 = "test";
char* string2 = "test";
assert((strcmp(string1.c_str(), string2)) || (string1.c_str() == string2));
```

is comparing the address where string1.c_str() is stored with the address where string2 is stored, and they will be different.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not familiar with C char* content comparison syntax, wasn't aware this was just checking pointer values (makes sense in retrospect).